# git log format for mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial

I like the way git displays its log(like in the man pages format). Is there any way I could customize mercurial to display its log(or glog) in a similar format?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing that by 'man pages format' you mean allowing you to scroll backwards and forwards in the output. You can accomplish the same thing in mercurial using the [pager extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PagerExtension). It can be accomplished by adding the following to your .hgrc:

```
[pager]
pager = LESS='FSRX' less
[extensions]
pager =
```

the `FSRX` arguments to less let it show any colored output you might have `hg log` showing.

Comment: Also useful: The [AutoPager](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AutopagerExtension) extension -- only uses a pager if the content to show exceeds the current terminal size.

Comment: @oben-sonne: This shouldn't be necessary, if you use less with -F, which causes less to quit itself if the output fits on the terminal without scrolling

Comment: why isn't it `pager = less -FSRX` ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a formatting that resembles git logs, put this in your .hgrc:

```
[alias]
vlog = log --template '\033[0;33mcommit: {rev}:{node}\n\033[0mAuthor: {author}\nDate:   {date|rfc822date}\n\n\t{desc|strip|fill68|tabindent}\n\n'
```

Here's a sample output. (In a terminal, the commit-line is colored).

```
$ cd code/mercurial
$ hg vlog
commit: 16004:7d12b2d3a83d44271b3aa515fe8d211e47bac2c0
Author: Matt Mackall <mpm@selenic.com>
Date:   Fri, 27 Jan 2012 18:43:31 -0600

        merge with i18n

commit: 16003:0d898ebb424ee85da76bc41584b14ac391549077
Author: Alexander Sauta <demosito@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri, 27 Jan 2012 12:25:02 +0400

        i18n-ru: synchronized with bf502ccc46d7; fuzzies removed

commit: 16002:384f7521c79152d6d197c0659f81e099067cadc3
Author: Nikolaj Sjujskij <sterkrig@myopera.com>
Date:   Thu, 26 Jan 2012 16:56:11 +0400

        i18n-ru: fix typos in `resolve` help

         * help entry is called 'merge-tools', not 'merge-tool';
         * envvar is called HGMERGE, not HGEMERGT.

commit: 16001:fcf66193b18699141e1da1ef4de4795d62a658cb
Author: Matt Mackall <mpm@selenic.com>
Date:   Thu, 26 Jan 2012 20:34:57 -0600

        merge: defer symlink flag merging to filemerge (issue3200)

        Previously, we could change a normal file into a corrupt symlink
        when trying to merge a symlink flag. Now, we leave the flag alone
        and let filemerge deal with it (usually by a prompt).

        We also drop a redundant flag setting after filemerge (now dealt
        with by ms.resolve) that would cause similar corruption.
```

Comment: 1,5 years later. I searched stackoverflow for a mercurial "git log" template and found this answer, that I had written and forgotten about! +1 to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think Den figured out what you mean, but if you're actually looking to alter the output stylistically you can do that with the `--style` command.  Examples:

```
$ hg log --style xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
<logentry revision="13480" node="69418d4525d166793bc63789b2bd64fcc3d84401">
<branch>stable</branch>
<tag>tip</tag>
<author email="tamizhgeek@gmail.com">Azhagu Selvan SP</author>
<date>2011-02-24T01:14:15+05:30</date>
<msg xml:space="preserve">convert/svn: abort operation when python bindings are not available
 ...
```

and

```
$ hg log --style changelog -l
2011-02-24  Azhagu Selvan SP  <tamizhgeek@gmail.com>

    * hgext/convert/subversion.py:
    convert/svn: abort operation when python bindings are not available

    Subversion python bindings check was not present in svn_sink source
    class which made it fail while using svn as destination repository.
    Added a more maintainble svn bindings check for svn_source and
    svn_sink classes.
    [69418d4525d1] [tip] <stable>
...
```